# how to check if member has a specific role

Tags: java, bots, discord, discord-jda

I wanna perform this command for my discord bot to add a role to a member.

```
public class team1Command implements ServerCommands {
    public void performCommand(Member m, TextChannel channel, Message message) {
    m.getGuild().addRoleToMember(message.getMember(), message.getGuild().getRoleById(the ID of team 1)).queue();
    channel.sendMessage("you joined team 1").queue();
    }
}
```

Now I want the command to work only if the member doesn't have the role "team 2"

Answer (score 0):

I´m not very familiar with the discord api but what about something like this:

```java
if(m.getGuild().getRoleById(the ID of team 2) != null) {
    ....
}
```

code formatting in your question would be nice by the way

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**, here is a code example:

```
Role role = guild.getRoleById(661155250123702302L);

if(member.getRoles().contains(role)) {
    // Member has the role
}else {
    // Member dont has the role
}
```

You just have to change the RoleID to the id of the role you want, you can get the id of a role by going to the "*Server Settings*"  of your Discord Server, go to "*Roles*", and right click your role and click "*Copy ID*".

If you dont see "*Copy ID*" you have to enable the "*Discord Developer*" mode by opening your "*User Settings*", go to "*Appearance*", scroll down to "*Advanced*" and turn on "*Developer Mode*".

Have fun, I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

There's no such feature in the doc for now.
You can still do this:

```
boolean hasRole;
  for(int i=0; i<builder.getGuildById(guild).getMemberById(userId).getRoles().size(); i++){
    if("RoleName".equals(builder.getGuildById(guild).getMemberById(userId).getRoles().get(i).getName())){
      hasRole = true;
    }
  }
```

Then, for true `if (hasRole)` or false `if (!hasRole)`